# Mysql pooling in node.js, should I use only one pool?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

Here's the issue: When I use my local environment MYSQL I get no issues when not using MYSQL pools, however, when I connect to the remote DB that I want to use for production, I get an error about too many connections (it says the current amount of connections is 10).

So here's what I did to solve the issue:

```
 if (typeof GLOBAL.connection === 'undefined') {
        GLOBAL.connection = mysql.createPool({
          connectionLimit : 10,
          host     : this.host,
          user     : this.user,
          password : this.password,
          database : this.database
        });
    }

    this.connection = GLOBAL.connection;
```

This solves the issue by creating one global pool, that all queries must run through. The only "problem" as I can see it is that now I have this pool sitting in my global variable.

Each time my queries run it instantiates a new Query(); object, which contains the above code in it. I'm basically just trying to find out if this has repercussions that I can't currently see, that may bite me in the butt later?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please run this and update your question with the answer? `show variables like "max_connections";`

Comment: @evanv the result was 4000

Comment: I am using global pool variable put whenever I test using load tester only 1 connection is created in MySQL [can see in MySQL webbench], why it is creating only 1 connection when 500 requests per second happening per second.